# Sending a message to a contact through my app?

Tags: android, sms, contacts

I want my application to show a list of all contacts..... 
The user can select single or multiple contacts and then send a message to them....

Its similar to a messaging app so I guess it must be possible through code..

I haven't got any code as of now

someone please help me out with this....

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Next time try to do it by your own, there is a lot of references in Internet about this

Comment: what you want to do you want to send a SMS or you want to send messages from internet like whats app and viber

Answer (score 1):

To send an SMS:

```
public void sendSMS(){
    SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
    String number = eTextMblNumber.getText().toString();
    String msg = eTextMsg.getText().toString();
    sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, msg, null, null);
}
```

And in your manifest add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html)

Comment: I know the code for sms , but wat boutfor getting the number by selecting a cotact from the list??